# Save scrapy item to a Postgres table based on a condition

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I'm creating a price monitor with web scraping from scrapy. I would like to save new items in a table called product and if the product price changed with time, save it in another table called product_change.

Any tips or thoughts?

Something like:

table: product

id url price date (when the item was **scraped** for the first time)

table: product_change

id url new_price date (when the item price changed)

with id a unique number that identifies the product.

I already create the items.py but can't figure out how to configure pipelines.py for this project.

Comment: What have you tried so far from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrapy%5D+postgresql ?

Answer (score 0):

**In pipelines.py add:**

```
import time

import psycopg2


    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        hostname = 'host name'
        username = 'postgres username'
        password = 'postgres password'
        database = 'postgres database'
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.cur.close()
        self.connection.close()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()    
        self.cur.execute( """SELECT id FROM product WHERE url='%s'  """ % item['url'])
        if self.cur.rowcount:
            result = self.cur.fetchone()
            self.cur.execute("""insert into product_change (id,url,new_price,"date") values (%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING""", 
            (result[0],item['url'],item['price'],time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
            self.connection.commit()        
        else:
            self.cur.execute("""insert into product (url,price,"data") values (%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING""", 
            (item['url'],item['price'],time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
            self.connection.commit()        

        return item
```